# Reading mov files with VideoReader

Tags: matlab, video

I'm trying to read a .mov movie file into MATLAB as follows:

```
v=VideoReader('file.mov');
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error using VideoReader/init (line 619)
Could not read file due to an unexpected error. Reason: Error Creating
Source Reader Reason: Unknown error 0xC00D36C4

Error in VideoReader (line 172)
            obj.init(fileName);
```

How can I resolve this, or what is the source of the problem?

I'm using MATLAB version R2017a, 64-bit & Windows 7 Enterprise.

The movie plays well on Quicktime.

Comment: Are you able to play that file outside MATLAB ? Try in Windows Media Player

Comment: @SardarUsama, I can play it with quicktime, with windows media player no.

Comment: Try installing [3ivx](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/3ivx.htm).

Comment: @SardarUsama, it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the reasons for that error are:

1. Unsupported file format.
2. Missing Codec.
3. File is corrupted.

In your case, since you're using Windows 7, [point#1 should not be a problem](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.html#busqd20-3) because `.mov` format is supported for Windows 7 and later. Since you are able to play that file with Quicktime, so the third possibility is also not valid. Missing Codec seems to be an issue in your case. Search the web for the codec for `.mov` files and install it and then run your code again.

Comment: followed your instructions and it is fine now. Cheers.

Comment: @jarhead Which codec did you install btw? (for future visitors of this post)